# Caching Views with altered query

Tags: 7, views

I have a view showing on taxonomy terms which shows popular nodes from same category of taxonomy terms.

Category - Taxonomy Terms - Nodes

Lets say Term A and Term B both are same category. On Term A page, we display popular nodes from Term B and other terms in same category.

This is done by modifying view query using `hook_views_query_alter`.

We can't find a way to successfully cache the output of this as there is no clear argument to be used as cache_id.

I have tried using Views Custom Cache module but it produces erratic results.

Any other ideas to cache this view?